# Time reverse transformation of 4-potential and its relation to Lorentz transformation

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, field-theory, conventions, time-reversal-symmetry

Until now, I thought electromagnetic potential $A^{\mu}(x)$ transform like $x^{\mu}$ under the Lorentz transformation:
$$A^{\mu}(x)=\Lambda^{\mu}_{\ \nu}A^{\nu}(x).$$
But according to time reversal symmetry of governing equations, $A^{\mu}(x)=(A^{0}(x), A^{j}(x))$ transform under the time inverse transformation:
$$A’^{\mu}(x’)=(A^{0}(x), -A^{j}(x))\neq (-A^{0}(x), A^{j}(x))= \Lambda^{\ \ \ \mu}_{T\ \ \nu}A^{\nu}(x）$$ (where $ \Lambda_{T}$ is the time inverse transformation and first equal follows from $B’(x’)=-B(x)$ & $E’(x’)=E(x)$ under the time inverse). I feel this is inconsistent.

In addition to this, according to the Smith’s linked PDF (http://www.physics.usu.edu/Wheeler/TopicPlugins/SpecialRelativityMaster.pdf#page17), usual time reversal transformation $T$ ( which replace $t$ by $-t$) is different from time reversal in Lorentz transformation: $\Lambda_{T\ \ \ \nu}^{\ \ \mu}=diag(-1,1,1,1). $ This is because Sometimes $T$ does not keep Lorentz norm (e.g. $(x^{\mu}+p^{\mu})(x_{\mu}+p_{\mu})$), and it does not act all 4-vectors in same way (e.g. $p’^{\mu}=(E, -{ \bf p}) \neq \Lambda_{T\ \ \ \nu}^{\ \ \mu}p^{\nu})$. I guess this is true, but why is $\Lambda_{T\ \ \ \nu}^{\ \ \mu}=diag(-1,1,1,1)$ called as time reversal? I feel this name is very misleading.

Can somebody explain this? I would misunderstand  4-vectors and concepts of covariant and contravariant.

Comment: More accurately, it depends on Newton’s second law. Because EOM has the time inversal symmetry, E and B are transformed as E’(x’)=E(x) and B’(x’)=-B(x) under the time inverse transformation. Thus, $A^{\mu}(x)$ is transformed like $ A’^{\mu}(x’)=(A^{0}(x), -A^{j}(x))$. This is what I mentioned above.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question so I deleted my previous comments.

Comment: Charged particles’ EOM $m\frac{d^{2}x_{i}}{dt’^{2}}$=$q{E’_{i}(x’)+$\epsilon_{ijk} \frac{dx_{j}}{dt’}B’_{k}(x’)$ and EOM has time reversal invariance, so $E’(x’)=E(x)$ and $B’(x’)=-B(x)$ must be satisfied (because velocity transform like $\frac{dx_{j}}{dt’}=-\frac{dx_{j}}{dt}$). But this means four-potential transform like $A’^{\mu}(x’)=(A^{0}, -A^{j})$ because $E’(x’)=-gradA’^{0}(x’)-\partial_{t} {\bf A’(x’)}$ and $B’(x’)=rot{\bf A’(x’)}$. I feel this is inconsistent because $A’^{\mu}(x’)=(-A^{0}, A^{j})$ must be satisfied from the four vector transformation.

Comment: Oh, okay. What I am confused is in my bottom comment.

Comment: [This paper](http://www.physics.usu.edu/Wheeler/TopicPlugins/SpecialRelativityMaster.pdf#page17) distinguishes “chronicity”, the Lorentz transformation negating the time component of any four-vector, and “time reversal”, the non-Lorentz transformation negating $t$.

Comment: I’ve upvoted because I would like to see a clear answer.

Comment: In the QFT community these two notions of time-reversal are usually referred to as $T$ and $CT$, where $C$ denotes charge-conjugation: $C(A)=-A$. The two operations $T$ and $CT$ are both symmetries of the theory, you can call either of them "time-reversal" (they both reverse the time-direction, they act differently on the fields; in this case, the difference is just a global sign). In [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/582292/84967) I explain how different symmetries may act on fields, and how there is no unique way.

Comment: Thank you Smith and AFT. I could deepen my understanding about time reversal. But there is one thing I remain being confused. It is in Smith’s linked PDF. In that pdf, author said time reversal of Lorentz transformation $\Lambda_{T\ \ \ \nu}^{\ \ \mu}=diag(-1,1,1,1)$ is not equal to either T or CT.

Comment: This is because Lorentz transformation is defined as keeping $g^{\mu\nu}\Lambda^{\rho}_{\mu} \Lambda^{\sigma}_{\nu}=g^{\sigma\rho}$ and thus all $ \Lambda^{\mu}_{\nu}$ must act all four vector in the same way, but $p’^{\mu}=(E, -{\bf p})\ \ (\neq \Lambda_{T\ \ \ \nu}^{\ \ \mu}\ p^{\nu})$ under T or CT and sometimes T&CT don’t keep Lorentz norm, so T&CT are not equal to $\Lambda_{T\ \ \ \nu}^{\ \ \mu}$ and not Lorentz transformation. I guess this is true. But if this is true, why is $\Lambda_{T\ \ \ \nu}^{\ \ \mu}=diag(-1,1,1,1)$ called as “time inversal” ? I feel it is very misleading.

Comment: Certainly,  $\Lambda^{\ \ \mu}_{T\ \ \ \nu}$ looks like time reversal. But it acts all 4-vectors in same way and this feature  is not in neither T nor CT.  So  I feel $\Lambda^{\ \ \mu}_{T\ \ \ \nu}$ is more stricter than T and CT. Is this true?